# Cannot start Rails Application ('no such file to load --rubygems')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ran this command:`ruby script/server -e production` in my RedMine root folder, didn't get anywhere, got this error:

```
/home/xxx/public_html/xxx.com/thor/redmine-1.1.2/config/boot.rb:113:in `require': no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)
     from /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/thor/redmine-1.1.2/config/boot.rb:113
     from script/server:2:in `require'
     from script/server:2
```

So, being said, rubygems is installed, but I don't know how or where to include a line of code or anything to designate that it's working properly. Anyways, hope someone can be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting a `require 'rubygems'` in your `config/environment.rb` file - that should fix the problem.

Comment: This is a question from 2011, but it worked for me when I did the change, I just uncommented the line, there was already a line with `require 'rubygems'` present.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple installs of ruby (old versions of os x without gem installed) and so you aren't using the correct binary?  run 'which ruby' and 'which gem' to verify they are what you expect.

Comment: ruby is giving me /usr/local/bin/ruby and gem is /usr/bin/gem